# How to have a TypeScript array with different child types?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Parent {
    id: number;
}

interface ChildA extends Parent {
    desc: string;
}

interface ChildB extends Parent {
    eatable: boolean;
}

let arr: Array<Parent> = []

arr.push({
    id: 1,
    desc: "test"
});

arr.push({
    id: 2,
    eatable: false
});
```

I have two different types with shared properties in my webapp, and i'd like to be able to have instances of these be stored in an array, to loop through when i only need to display the shared properties. How can i do this? The above code gives a type error.

**Update #1:**

How come i am not able to do the above, but i am able to do the following? This gives me, type-wise, exactly the same as the top example.

```
let arr: Parent[] = []
let tmp_arr: (ChildA | ChildB)[] = [];
arr = tmp_arr;

tmp_arr.push({
    id: 1,
    desc: "test"
});

tmp_arr.push({
    id: 2,
    eatable: false
});

for (let child of arr) {
    console.log(child.id);
} 
//(console: 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stating that your array has only members with `id` property but they have more fields. In order to achieve what you need we can use union operator `|`

```
 Array<ChildA | ChildB>
```

Also I propose to model types differently, consider:

```
interface Base {
    id: number;
}

interface ChildA extends Base {
    desc: string;
}

interface ChildB extends Base {
    eatable: boolean;
}

type Final = ChildA | ChildB;

// and now
let arr: Array<Final> = []
```

Additional info because of the question in the comment

```
{
    let arr: Parent[] = [{ id: 1 }]
    let tmp_arr: (ChildA | ChildB)[] = [];
    tmp_arr = arr; // error as Parent is not assinable to ChildA | ChildB
}
{
    let arr: Parent[] = []
    let tmp_arr: (ChildA | ChildB)[] = [];
    arr = tmp_arr; // no error as ChildA | ChildB has all fields required by Parent
}
```

You can assign type which is more restricted(is a subset) to the more loose type, but you cannot in other way round because if you do your type does not pass the requirements. For example you cannot use `Parent[]` as `(ChildA | ChildB)[]` as `Parent` has less fields

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of the union operator. This does however raise another question, as posed in my update :)

Comment: TS is structural typed language, doing arr = tmp_arr; you are not changing the type, `[]` is valid member for both types so it can be passed.

Comment: Added you more info in the answer

Comment: Right, so i was originally hoping i could push ChildA and ChildB directly to a Parent[] array, since they have all required fields. It's still not clear to me why having all required fields is good enough for assigning arrays, but not for pushing to them. But i guess, in the end, that's just a design choice.

Comment: such behavior works only with literal types, so if you put this to the variable it will work as I said. Literals types are strict in both ways